What is the correct syntax for calling the function with parameters in Vue3?
I am trying to scroll through different options that are stored in an array, by using the function below and passing it the correct parameters. But no matter what syntax I try, it doesn't seem to work.
This is my array and the ref variable i use:
const clothingTypes = ['blazerAndShirt', 'blazerAndSweater', 'collarAndSweater', 'graphicShirt'];
const selectedClothingType = ref(clothingTypes[0]);

I have tried calling the following function in two different ways:
const nextType = (array, refVariable) => {
    const currentIndex = array.indexOf(refVariable.value);
    const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % array.length;
    refVariable.value = array[nextIndex];
};

@click="() => nextType(clothingTypes, selectedClothingType)"

and
@click="nextType(clothingTypes, selectedClothingType)"

But I get the same error in console:
Uncaught TypeError: can't assign to property "value" on "blazerAndShirt": not an object
What is the correct syntax?

Your error is due to the parameters you pass to your function.
When calling nextType(clothingTypes, selectedClothingType) from the vue template, the ref are unwrapped. That means you don't pass in the ref, but the string value directly:
// clothingTypes === 'blazerAndShirt'
function nextType(clothingTypes, selectedClothingType) {
  // so it ends up doing
  'blazerAndShirt'.value = array[nextIndex];
  // which is not possible.
}


Here is a better and simpler approach to your problem: store the current index of the element you want to show.
const clothingTypes = ['blazerAndShirt', 'blazerAndSweater', 'collarAndSweater', 'graphicShirt'];
const currentItemIndex = ref(0)

function nextItem() {
  currentItemIndex = (currentItemIndex + 1) % clothingTypes.length
}

const currentItem = computed(() => clothingTypes[currentItemIndex])

In the template, just do:
@click="nextItem"

And it will automatically update the computed property currentItem, that you can use in your template.

Nice to see you helping here again.

Unfortunately Vue unwrap refs in a template so its value passed as argument rather than the ref itself, you can use an utility to fix that:
See on Vue SFC Playground
import { ref, computed } from "vue"

export default function(val){
  const value = ref(val);
  return computed({
    get: () => value,
    set: v => value.value = v
  });
}

Usage:
<script setup>
import unwrappedRef from './UnwrappedRef';
const clothingTypes = ['blazerAndShirt', 'blazerAndSweater', 'collarAndSweater', 'graphicShirt'];
const selectedClothingType = unwrappedRef(clothingTypes[0]);

const nextType = (array, refVariable) => {
    const currentIndex = array.indexOf(refVariable.value);
    const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % array.length;
    refVariable.value = array[nextIndex];
};
</script>

<template>
  <div>{{ selectedClothingType }}</div>
  <button @click="nextType(clothingTypes, selectedClothingType)">Click me</button>
</template>



I don't see any benefit of passing the state as parameters, just call the function that change the state without any parameters :
<script setup>
const clothingTypes = ['blazerAndShirt', 'blazerAndSweater', 'collarAndSweater', 'graphicShirt'];
const selectedClothingType = unwrappedRef(clothingTypes[0]);

const nextType = () => {
    const currentIndex = clothingTypes.indexOf(selectedClothingType.value);
    const nextIndex = (currentIndex + 1) % clothingTypes.length;
    selectedClothingType.value = clothingTypes[nextIndex];
};
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="nextType">Click me</button>
</template>


I want to pass parameters because i want to reuse the function for different arrays.

In this case think about defining a composable (for example useArrayNavigation) that takes this data as parameters and return the function nextType that change the inner state

As noted in other answer, the problem is ref unwrapping, selectedClothingType is transparently unwrapped to selectedClothingType.value in templates.
If a function is reusable and can potentially receive a ref as an argument, e.g. when used in component script, it needs to be flexible enough to accept different value types:
const nextType = (array, valueOrRef) => {
  const value = unref(valueOrRef);
  const currentIndex = array.indexOf(value);
  ...

